# Indentation Line In IDLE

Tags: python

I want to have an indentation line so I don't have to eyeball an indent. Is this possible on IDLE Python?
For example:

```
while True:
| print("Hello World")
|  
print("HI")
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get IDLE to display indentation guides. Bear in mind that IDLE is mainly for running small programs interactively and not for large-scale project development. When you get to the point of really needing indentation guides, it's time to look around for a big IDE like PyCharm or VSCode or Wing. And it's also hard to see how indentation guides would work with the `>>>` prompt.

Comment: I understand that, and I have used PyCharm, but a lot of modules don't work on PyCharm. For example the keyboard module

Comment: I'm not sure that I would call that "a lot of modules". Naturally, for an IDE to work intuitively it has to take charge of your keyboard. If your code does that too, then conflicts are going to be unavoidable. For that I suggest you use a text editor like Notepad++ which is free, can do Python syntax highlighting, and has indentation guides, and run your programs from the command line so that there isn't an IDE to get in the way.